# Problem with point totals on Users page on Mechanics

Tags: bug

I'm seeing an issue with point totals on the [Users](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users) page for Mechanics, at least. Looking at a couple of other sites, I'm not seeing the issue there, but who knows.

If you look at Users "week" total, you'll see the following:

[image]

Yet if you go to my rep tab, you'll see:

[image]

Clearly I've only garnered 145 points for this week. I looked at GdD's point total and they have only gained 50, not 150 for the week. I've not looked any deeper than this. Looking at the Month tab, it appears to be spot on. I'm not sure if this is due to the new design changes SE has been working on, or what, but thought I'd bring it to light.

Comment: Worth noting that there's a similar bug report on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370044/weekly-users-reputation-score-hasnt-reset-for-the-new-week) and it's also doing the same thing here on MSE. It reset for some users but not all.

Comment: @Catija - Was there already a bug report created? I have no issue closing this question out and adding to it if there is.

Comment: I haven't seen one here on MSE, no. :) I'm mostly corroborating that it's not *only* an issue on Mechanics.

Comment: @Catija - Thank you much. Appreciate the follow-up.